# How does the CanBeSystemVolume function work during unattended installation

Tags: windows, winpe

In my case I'd like to modify the "unattend.xml" file to install OS to the disk which supports installation.

Setting fixed disk index implicates setting up boot options which is not the prefered when you change disks very often and you actually want the installation to be unattended.

During the unattended installation in Windows PE the installer is executing the function called `CanBeSystemVolume`. This seems to be the solution for my problem but I can't find the definition of it anywhere. Looking for a way to detect possible system volume also gave me no results as it shows me results connected with adjusting system volume (sound).

I've also tried `diskpart` but there's no difference in details between disk which could be system volume and those which could not.

Does anyone have any idea of how to check it?